# Understanding definable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, predicate-logic

I'm facing some difficulties in understanding what its mean to prove that a set is a definable set. Below is an example of a question that was given in our class, with the solution for this question. Could someone please help me understand the solution, and how to deal with similar questions?

Let `τ = <f,R>` be a dictionary such that `f` is a 2-local function, and `R` is 1-local relation.

M defined as `M = ⟨ℚ+, . , <1⟩` is a structure for `τ`.

**A**.  Show that 1 is definable in M

**B**.  Show that the relation `{ (a,b) ∈ ℚ² | a is the opposite of b }` is definable in M.

**The answers are as follows:**

**A**. Create a formula `α1(x)` such that `M ⊨_z α1(x)` if and only if `z(x) = 1`:

```
α1(x) = ∀y(f(x,y) = y)
```

**B**.  Create a formula `α2(x,y)` such that `M ⊨_z α2(x,y)` if and only if `z(x),z(y)` are opposite :

`α2(x,y) = ∃z(α1(z) ∧ (f(x,y) = z )`

Comment: Do you perhaps mean “inverse” (instead of “opposite”)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a formula $\varphi(x)$ with a free variable $x$ such that your structure models $\varphi(x)$ iff $x$ is assigned to $1$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, a unique and easy way to define $1$ is
\begin{equation}
\varphi(x)\equiv \forall y (f(x,y) = y)
\end{equation}
and then $\varphi(x)$ holds iff $x$ is the multiplicative identity, i.e. $x$ is assigned to $1$.
As for the relation, you may first need to define $0$: you can do it with $Z(x) \equiv \forall y(f(x,y)=x)$ and then you can define the relation using the fact that $a$ is the opposite of $b$ is the same as $ab < 0$, so a possible route would be $\exists v(Z(v) \wedge R(f(a,b),v))$ where you say “$v = 0$ and $ab < v$”.